# Godot 4.0: Mouse not interacting with CollisionShape2D

Tags: mouseevent, godot

When I started my game I was completely new to Godot, and made many poor choices when designing my node structure. Several months later I fixed the node structure, only to discover that my CollisionShape2D objects were no longer interacting with the mouse; no response to _on_mouse_entered, _on_mouse_exited, or mouse clicks. I assume something is consuming the mouse inputs, but I am at a loss after troubleshooting for several days.

So far I have:

- Turned on "Visible Collision Shapes" to show that they were still present
- Verified the Subviewport mouse filter is set to "Stop"
- Verified that overlapping nodes have their mouse filters set to "Ignore"
- Placed the Subviewport as low as possible to increase its input event precedence
- Moved all other StaticBody2D nodes to the Subviewport node
- Moved all other Sprite2D nodes to the Subviewport node

[image: Node Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is some `Control` consuming the input, and you need to set its `mouse_filter` to "Ignore" (`MOUSE_FILTER_IGNORE`). A `Control` will take precedence over a `Node2D` regardless of where they are in the scene tree.

If you are having trouble figuring out which `Control` is consuming the input, you can run the game from the editor, go to the Debugger panel and on the Misc tab Godot will show you what have you clicked.

---

For your `CollisionObject2D` to be able to take pointing input, you want to make sure their `input_pickable` of your is set to `true` (this was the default in Godot 3.x, but it defaults to `false` in Godot 4.x, so this is a potential gotcha).

---

For the case of the `SubViewport`, if you want what is inside to take input, make sure that the `gui_disable_input` of the `SubViewport` is set to `true`, and also - as I believe you have done - that the `mouse_filter` of the `SubViewportContainer` is set to "Stop" (`MOUSE_FILTER_STOP`).

Comment: As always, thank you for your comprehensive answer. That said, I was not able to get the CollisionObject2D to take input until I set the SubViewportContainer mouse filter to "Pass". The debugger miscellaneous screen was reflecting that the SubviewportContainer was capturing clicks with the mouse filter set to "Stop", but nothing was happening. Switched it to "Pass" and functionality returned.... it's a mystery to me.